# Observable/BehaviorSubject not working in different modules of Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, observable, angular10, behaviorsubject

I have 1 feature module (`Fund module`) that displays fund data in one of its components and an `AppModule` that displays Advisor data. Fund data and Advisor data have one to many relationship.
Fund component gets data from services defined in the AppModule.

Data are passed to the Fund module using `BehaviorSubject` as data might change if the user updates or modifies the data in AppModule.
The subscription of the data in not working correctly. The fund module only displays the value (**10**) that the `BehaviorSubject` is initialized with. It doesn't display the updated value (**100**), nor does the subscription work properly to display the values second time.

Here's the code:

**Service in AppModule**:

```
test = new BehaviorSubject<number>(10);

getTest(): Observable<number> {
  return this.test.asObservable();
}

public updateLocalData(sleeves: Sleeve[]): void {
  .... update logic
  this.test.next(100);
}
```

**FundDataComponent in Fund Module**

```
changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,

   ngOnInit(): void {
    this.test = this.service.getTest().subscribe((number) => {
      this.number = number;
      console.log(number);    // get's called only once to display 10
    });
  }
```

Comment: Is the fund module lazy loaded ?

Comment: Where do you call updateLocalData?

Comment: @korteee no, it is not lazily loaded

Comment: @WillAlexander I am calling updateLocalData in one of the components (EditDataComponent) in AppModule

Comment: could you reproduce it on stackblitz?

Comment: From Angular 9, you can say that the service was "global": https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services#using-providedin. This `providedIn:root` else you has two services differents

Answer (score 0):

Create a model - resource.ts:

```js
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { refCount, publishReplay } from 'rxjs/operators';

export class StreamResource {
   private loading = false;
   private behaviorSubject: BehaviorSubject<any>;
   public readonly obs: Observable<any>;

   constructor(defaultValue?: any) {
       this.behaviorSubject = new BehaviorSubject(defaultValue);
       this.obs = this.behaviorSubject.asObservable().pipe(publishReplay(1), refCount());
   }

   request(method: any): void {
       if (method && !this.loading) {
           this.loading = true;
           method().toPromise().then((data: any) => {
               if (data) { this.update(data); }
               this.loading = false;
           });
       }
   }

   getValue() {
       return this.behaviorSubject.getValue();
   }

   update(data: any) {
       this.behaviorSubject.next(data);
   }

   refresh() {
       const data = this.getValue();
       if (data) { this.update(data); }
   }
}
```

Create a StreamService

```js
import { StreamResource } from '../models/resource';
public test = new StreamResource(10);

...

getTest() {
    this.test.request(() => this.testService.getTest());
}
```

How to use?

```
  constructor(private streamService: StreamService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.streamService.test.obs.subscribe((data: any) => {
      if (!data) {
        return this.streamService.getTest();
      } else {
        this.test = data;
      }
    });
```

Comment: @PritamBohra https://github.com/dm-grinko/angular-rxjs-template